# wrong query result in mysqli

Tags: mysql, sql

hi there I have a filed with publish=3 value

but this query print it!(it shouldn't)

```
 SELECT * FROM article WHERE publish BETWEEN 0 AND 2 AND feature = '1' 
 AND sid = '3' OR sid = '4' OR sid = '5' OR sid = '6' OR sid = '7' 
 OR sid = '8' OR sid = '9' OR sid = '10' AND created BETWEEN 0 
 AND 1446078164 ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 0, 6
```

what is my wrong?

**more info:**

for where,there are 4 main clustered:
    WHERE publish BETWEEN 0 AND 2

```
AND feature = '1'

AND sid = '3' OR sid = '4' OR sid = '5' OR sid = '6' OR sid = '7' 
 OR sid = '8' OR sid = '9' OR sid = '10'

AND created BETWEEN 0 AND 1446078164
```

Comment: too many weird conditions makes it hard to read and understand

Comment: You really should use parenthesis to keep track what's going on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need parentheses and probably `in`.  I am guessing the logic you want is:

```
SELECT *
FROM article
WHERE publish BETWEEN 0 AND 2 AND
      feature = '1' AND
      sid IN ('3', '4', '5', '6', '7' , '8', '9', '10') AND
      created BETWEEN 0 AND 1446078164
ORDER BY id DESC
LIMIT 0, 6;
```